# How to know username and password of Oracle 10g Ex?

Tags: oracle10g

Actually, I forgot my username and password of Oracle 10g Ex. Are there any way to find them?

Comment: Actually I already saw that but it's not working for me ,may be I didn't understand properly so I posted it again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Log into the database server as a user belonging to ‘dba’ [unix ] or ‘ora_dba’ [windows ] group , typically ‘oracle’, or an administrator on your windows machine. Then you will be able to log in to Oracle as SYS user, and change the SYSTEM password by doing the following

```
$ sqlplus "/ as sysdba"
SQL*Plus: Release 9.2.0.1.0 - Production on Mon Apr 5 15:32:09 2004

Copyright (c) 1982, 2002, Oracle Corporation.  All rights reserved.

Connected to:
Oracle9i Enterprise Edition Release 9.2.0.1.0 - Production
With the OLAP and Oracle Data Mining options
JServer Release 9.2.0.1.0 - Production

SQL> show user

USER is "SYS"

SQL> passw system
Changing password for system
New password:
Retype new password:
Password changed
SQL> quit
```

Next, we need to change the password of SYS:

```
$ sqlplus "/ as system"
SQL*Plus: Release 9.2.0.1.0 - Production on Mon Apr 5 15:36:45 2004

Copyright (c) 1982, 2002, Oracle Corporation.  All rights reserved.

SP2-0306: Invalid option.
Usage: CONN[ECT] [logon] [AS {SYSDBA|SYSOPER}]
where <logon>  ::= <username>[/<password>][@<connect_string>] | /
Enter user-name: system
Enter password:

Connected to:
Oracle9i Enterprise Edition Release 9.2.0.1.0 - Production
With the OLAP and Oracle Data Mining options
JServer Release 9.2.0.1.0 - Production

SQL> passw sys
Changing password for sys
New password:
Retype new password:
Password changed
SQL> quit
```

You should now be able to log on the SYS and SYSTEM users, with the passwords you just typed in.